# UICollectionView overlapping cells

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I am having a UICollectionView that I create and add programatically but for some reason at runtime section 1 and section 2 are overlapping, they both start in the same place:

Here is my Implementation (the code is swift 2.3 since this is a project requirement):

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = lightGreyColor
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 15, right: 0)
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0.5
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0.5
    layout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirection.Vertical
  //  layout.headerReferenceSize = CGSize(width: view.bounds.width, height: 30)

    let collectionViewFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.bounds.width, height: viewHeight)
    collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: collectionViewFrame, collectionViewLayout: layout)

    collectionView.allowsSelection = true
    collectionView.bounces = true
    collectionView.scrollEnabled = true
    collectionView.hidden = false
    collectionView.pagingEnabled = false
    collectionView.backgroundColor = lightGreyColor
    collectionView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
    collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false

    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self

    view.addSubview(collectionView)

    collectionView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "SmallDiscoverItemCollectionViewCell", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle()), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "SmallDiscoverItemCollectionViewCell")

    collectionView.registerClass(NewDiscoverTopCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "NewDiscoverTopCollectionViewCell")
    collectionView.registerClass(TopHeaderCell.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "TopHeaderCell")

    greedoCollectionViewLayout = nil
    greedoCollectionViewLayout1().rowMaximumHeight = collectionView.bounds.width/1.8
    greedoCollectionViewLayout1().fixedHeight = false

}


func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {

    switch indexPath.section {
    case 0:
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.width, height: 200)
    case 1:
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.width, height: 200)
    default:
        return self.greedoCollectionViewLayout1().sizeForPhotoAtIndexPath(indexPath)
       }

   }
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
 switch (indexPath.section) {
    case 0: let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("NewDiscoverTopCollectionViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! NewDiscoverTopCollectionViewCell

        return cell

    case 1: let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("NewDiscoverTopCollectionViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! NewDiscoverTopCollectionViewCell

        return cell

    case 2: let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("SmallDiscoverItemCollectionViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SmallDiscoverItemCollectionViewCell
    let item = usersItems[indexPath.item]
    return cell
 }
```

This is the end result of the overlap: Section 0 and 1 and having green background while in between there is this gap. While section 2 has lots of images:

[image]

Comment: You should post a screenshot of the issue, for us to understand better what's going on

Comment: on it now ... will update the post in a few

Comment: And what exactly is overlapping??

Comment: section 1 and 2 as mentioned above ... if you look at section 2 you see there is something green in the background... that is section 1

Comment: ok... strange. Let me take a better look at your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some weird reason the UICollectionViewCell got initialise to a y position equal to its size. To fix that I have just added this in the UICollectionViewCell

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
let noProblemFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.width, height: frame.height)
super.init(frame: noProblemFrame)
```